# Fancybox works if I add a class manually but not with jQuery .addClass()

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2, addclass

I have the following JS code, which I add Fancybox classes to all hrefs on a page:

```
$(function(){ 

    //set target var
    var $targetTable = $('.photo-frame a');

    //loop trough each table and insert the fancybox class on the href tag
    $targetTable.each(function() {
        $targetTable.addClass('fancybox');
    });

});
```

This works because the fancybox class **is added**, but the fancybox is not triggered. But if I add this class manually in the browser-editor and click on the image fancybox **is triggered**.

I have also tried the following, but without result:

```
$('.photo-frame a').addClass('fancybox');
```

Does anyone have any idea where this may be due to?

Comment: it's the order you are doing it. please show where you trigger fancybox? (it will need to be triggered AFTER you add the classes)

Comment: `$targetTable` contains many elements. By writing `$targetTable.addClass('fancybox')`, you add the class to all the elements at once. No need for a each or a loop; you're just doing the exact same thing (adding a class to all the elements) several times in the loop. Your whole code can be rewritten : `$('.photo-frame a').addClass('fancybox');`

Comment: @JeremyThille I've done this also, but this is also not working for me. That's what makes it so strange.

Comment: Can you try and make a fiddle please?

Answer (score 0):

When you hardcode the class It works because its present when the DOM is build but its not the same with the later case.

You need to reinitialize `fancybox` by  `$(".fancybox").fancybox();`

```
$(function(){ 

    //set target var
    var $targetTable = $('.photo-frame a');

    //loop trough each table and insert the fancybox class on the href tag
    $targetTable.each(function() {
        $targetTable.addClass('fancybox');
    });

    $(".fancybox").fancybox();

});
```

Comment: ... or just `$('.photo-frame a').fancybox()`... Why do simple :)

Comment: initializing fancybox v2.x once is enough, no need to reinitialize

Answer (score 0):

Your code + the correct fancybox initialization works fine

```
$(function () {
    // initialize fancybox
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();

    //set target var
    var $targetTable = $('.photo-frame a');
    //loop trough each table and insert the fancybox class on the href tag
    $targetTable.each(function () {
        $targetTable.addClass('fancybox');
    });
});
```

**[image: JSFIDDLE]**

The following, as suggested by [void](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1496715/void), also works

```
$(function () {

    //set target var
    var $targetTable = $('.photo-frame a');
    //loop trough each table and insert the fancybox class on the href tag
    $targetTable.each(function () {
        $targetTable.addClass('fancybox');
    });

    // initialize fancybox
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

**[image: JSFIDDLE]**

This, as suggested by [Jeremy Thille](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1021703/jeremy-thille), also works

```
$(function () { 
    $('.photo-frame a').fancybox();

    // initialize fancybox
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

**[image: JSFIDDLE]**

... in any order

```
$(function () {    
    // initialize fancybox
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();

    $('.photo-frame a').fancybox();
});
```

**[image: JSFIDDLE]**

So, my guess? something in your code is triggering a js error that prevents your `addClass` code and fancybox from working.

You better check your errors before asking.

Comment: Of course it works in a jsfiddle environment and even in my page theFancybox class is set correctly. But what I mean is that the class "fancybox" despite being set, is not triggering any effect. But when I insert the class trough the browser editor, everything strarts to work. Next time better read before you give an answer please.

Comment: @Ramirez : so you are giving me the reason: there is a js error in your page that prevents fancybox from working. Possibilities: two different versions of jQuery, fancybox loaded before jQuery or not fancybox loaded at all (wrong path maybe?). If it's working in a jsfiddle, there is not a "strange" reason why it shouldn't work in your page. If you provide a link to a test page reproducing the issue, I can tell you why it doesn't work.